# Does a baby cry inside the womb?

Tags: pregnancy, crying

Considering [Music for gestation - what should baby be hearing while in the womb?](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/6806/music-for-gestation-what-should-baby-be-hearing-while-in-the-womb) that babies can hear sounds inside the womb, I also expect myself to hear the baby crying or making sounds inside the womb. I cannot hear anything from the baby's side.

Does a baby cry inside the womb? Or the crying process starts once he comes out? What's the logic behind this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You need air to pass over your vocal cords for vocalizations like an infants cry to start.  However, it has been [observed](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDQQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qi-01eITZaU&ei=xl1dUePKOIj88gSZuIGIAQ&usg=AFQjCNGUFpwBAWWiU-9G_4kHGICUFYq1SQ&sig2=8RgS_h8agUoQWyIr0YnCRw&bvm=bv.44770516,d.eWU) that fetuses in the womb will make crying-like movements with their mouths, so they're certainly practicing in utero for blasting our eardrums when they arrive.

Comment: +1 perfect: they're certainly practicing in utero for blasting our eardrums when they arrive